# Vertical Plane Tracking in Facebook's Spark AR Studio

Tags: javascript, enums, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am new to Javascript but I have been experimenting in Spark AR Studio making AR Experiences for Art school. I would like to be able to place images of my art on walls using the plane tracker element included in Spark AR. This requires changing the tracking from horizontal to vertical using scripting. There seems to be a way to change the tracking mode using the Enum TrackingMode with the value VERTICAL_PLANE however I do not understand how to implement this. I am sure that this is easier than it seems to me but if anyone could show me how its done I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this feature doesn't seem to work as expected. The only thing you can use from enum is "MOVING_OBJECT" and "PLANE".

You can use "fixedTargetTracker" to make your experience. For that you need to make good target image, [this article from Vuforia](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Optimizing-Target-Detection-and-Tracking-Stability.html) will explain what is a good target.

So just put yourObjects as a child of tracker and thats it.

[image]